# Force Celery to run next task in queue?

Tags: python, django, celery

Is there any way to make Celery recheck if there are any tasks in the main queue ready to be started? Will the remote command `add_consumer()` do the job?

The reason: I am running several concurrent tasks, which spawn multiple sub-processes. When the tasks are done, the sub-processes sometimes take a few seconds to finish, so because the concurrency limit is maxed out by sub-processes, a new task from the queue is never started. And because Celery does not check again when the sub-processes finish, the queue gets stalled with no active tasks. Therefore I want to add a periodical task that tells Celery to recheck the queue and and start the next task. How do I tell Celery this?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues):

> The add_consumer control command will tell one or more workers to start consuming from a queue. This operation is idempotent.

**Yes, `add_consumer` does what you want.** You could also combine that with a [periodic task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to "recheck the queue and start the next task" every so often (depending on your need)

Comment: No downvotes. I just removed my upvote, as you don't actually answer my problem, but just confirms my suspicion that "it looks like add_consumer does" the job.

Comment: Fair enough, but how does this not answer your question? Your question as-written is: "will the remote command add_consumer() do the job?" The answer is "yes." Please clarify. :)

Comment: I need a definite answer from someone who actually tried and knows. The docs are vague, which is why I asked in the first place. "start consuming from a queue" can mean multiple things when that queue is already being consumed from, but it is just on pause because the concurrency limit has been reached.